# CSOM : sharepoint is not logging the message for sharepoint app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I am using `Utility.LogCustomRemoteAppError()` to log the messages of provider hosted app.

But the above method is not working when it is used inside Remote event receiver(item updated etc..). Also none of the parameter is null.

What might be the reason for this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Asynchronous(ed) events, you need to wait for some time to get the log.

Basically the above method expects, client context, product id( id of your app , this you can find in appmanifest) and error message.

Follow these steps to monitor your apps

Go to SharePoint admin center (_layouts/15/online/tenantadminapps.aspx) --> Select apps--> monitor apps --> add your app .

Once your logic executes, if you get any errors, you can see them by clicking on View Errors icon in ribbon.